# In terms of betting, how would you say "You will get 5× in return if you win"?

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language

In terms of betting, how would you say "You will get 5× in return if you win"?

Answer (score 2):

You would likely "place the odds at **5 to one**."

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds#Gambling_odds_versus_probabilities)

Comment: I'm not really a betting man, but actually I think if you bet £1 on a horse that wins, and the bookie returns you £5, that would mean the odds were **4 to 1** (your winnings are 4 x £1 *plus* your £1 stake which you also get back).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A bookie who took your £1 bet at five to one but tried to fob you off with £5 total would find himself in trouble (though automated bookmakers like fruit machines or the National Lottery seem to get away with it). I believe OP is asking about a five-to-one bet.

Comment: @TimLymington: Like I said, I'm not really a betting man (I've only  been in a betting shop a couple of times in my life, and *that* was only to look for someone). The thing is in most informal contexts (betting between friends) the stake *never actually changes hands*. So if you bet someone £1 at 5:1 that you can drink him under the table, say, you should only expect to receive £5 when you win. Of course, in those circumstances your opponent would be *really* woozy, so you might persuade him to give you £6 anyway! (or maybe you get £0.20 - I'm really not too clued up on betting odds! :)

Comment: I think that should be 4 to 1, not 5. I.e. you will put 4 pounds into the pot for every 1 that the other person puts in, and the winner gets the pot.

Comment: The phrasing "five to one" implies that for every one you put in, you will get five back if you win (*including* your stake). This means that a bet of £1 at 5:1 returns £5. It doesn't matter if you exchanged money beforehand or not. If you put your 1 in before, you get 5 back including the 1. If you didn't put your 1 in before, you get 4 or pay 1 depending on victory. In a situation where one winner gets the pot, the odds are N:1 where N is the number of players (assuming all players ante the same amount).

Answer (score 1):

To say it in betting terms, you'd say that the odds are five to one, probably. In literal terms, you would read your sentence aloud as "You will get five times in return if you win".

Answer (score 1):

*You will get your money back **fivefold***

The suffix **[-fold](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fold_38)** means

> used with numbers to make adjectives and adverbs describing how much something increases
>   a fourfold increase (an increase in an amount that makes it four times larger than before)

Answer (score 1):

A four hundred percent return might work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for a slightly more rustic solution than those already presented, you could say "five will get you twenty-five," substituting any two sets of numbers that represent x and 5x.